# How to create the +/- button on the bottom of a tableview for OS X?

Tags: swift, macos

This is an example of what I wanted:

[image: Example]

How do I create those buttons on the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSSegmentedControl` with `NSAddTemplate` and `NSRemoveTemplate` template images for items.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SegmentedControl/Articles/SegmentedControlBasics.html).